# eclipse/xdebug launches 5 debuggers at the same time

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I am having some troubles with my debugger configs in eclipse.
As you can see in the pic, beside me PHP Web Application debug configuration (first one which is working fine), eclipse is also starting 5 times the Remote PHP Launch....

Specs:

XAMPP for OS X 5.6.14
Xdebug 2.2.5

```
zend_extension =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

I have no clue why.

[image]

Comment: Port 9001 is also configured in eclipse.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-) Please take a moment to read the guidelines for the site in the Help Center. You need to post a specific QUESTION in your "Question" so that people can compose a meaningful response.